# Is it possible for a runner to advance if the batter doesn't hit the ball?

Tags: baseball

Let's say the pitcher throws the ball but the batter does not hit it. Can someone at first,second or third proceed to the next base?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is called a [stolen base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolen_base) or a "steal" and is a relatively common occurrence in the game.

Comment: Not downvotinng but there should be a baseline on questions answered and this question is definitely below it.  The next question on the list is "What is it called when a hitter gets to third on their hit?"  Also you didn't even cover the entire answer which would be a stolen base, passed ball, or any type of error.

Comment: If you think that's a worthwhile debate, please start it on [meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/), not in comments. Just because you know lots about baseball doesn't mean everybody does; there are many parts of the world where the game just isn't played.

Comment: It is something easily researched.  Questions are supposed to be asked to find an answer that isn't easily googled or takes some sort of explaining.

Comment: Again: **take it to meta**.

Comment: Regardless, you can't update your answer or acknowledge that your answer was lacking in the comments.

Comment: @PhilipKendall This is already covered in the [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). "...Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself..." Because someone doesn't know about baseball doesn't absolve him/her from doing research.

Comment: Hillariously dry answer.

Answer (score -4):

Yes Definately .. If the next base is empty then only you can run, if not empty then you are called out as two players on same base occur.

[Reference Base Stealing](http://probaseballinsider.com/baseball-instruction/base-running/)

Comment: This is incorrect; two runners on the same base does not automatically mean an out - it is only *passing* the other runner that leads to an out. Of course, only one of the runners is entitled to the base so the other is at risk of being put out if tagged.